# Connecting two machines using Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I tried to connect two machines using Socket.

I put client code in Machine A:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {   
            Socket s = new Socket("IP ADDRESS",5555);
        //  Socket s = new Socket("localhost",6669);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            s.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Run the server code in Machine B

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555);
            Socket s = ss.accept(); //establishes connection 

            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            String  str = (String) dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("message= " + str);

            ss.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Both in machine in same network

But its not running and no error also coming in CMD.

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you sure that the IP Address of the server is correct?

Comment: and are you sure the two machine are in the same network?

Comment: Ya both is same network and IP also correct

Comment: can you change the Port number please?

Comment: Ya i tried it will wait for sometine and "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" appears in COnsole.

Comment: Check with netstat if the port is really open on machine B. Also check if there is a firewall that maybe blocks the connection.

Comment: Thanks ...Its resolved the prblm..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when I compile the code using "localhost" as the hostname, and run the client and server apps on the same machine ... it works.  The server receives the message and prints it.

From this, I conclude that the code is correct (enough) and the real problem is something to do with your networking; e.g.

- It might be a routing problem.
- It might be a firewall problem.
- There might be something wrong with your physical network or network interfaces.

However none of these are programming problems.